# Trouble getting Bootstrap controls to work in App

Tags: bootstrap-5

[enter image description here][1]I am trying to use several controls from Bootstarp in my website.  I use the Navigation controls (which work fine), and am trying to use Modal,  Carousel, Drop-up button, etc.  The script below shows the script tags in my shared _layout file.  I have tried multiple things from reading the documentation, but it seems that if one thing works, it breaks something else.

I cannot get the Drop-Up Button to work in my app at all, using any script options.  I have a simple test program that does work, but I am unable to determine what is different.

I have been operating on the assumption that I have the wrong versions of bootstrap or popper, but whatever I try something might work, but other things break.

I guess my questions are basic...Do I have to install bootstrap and Popper using Nuget, or can I just include the bundle?  When I try the bundle, it changes how my screens look.  Also navigation doesn't work.

In my test program, where everything seems to work, I didn't install anything (initially).  It was just the started site created by Visual studio.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />

@*    With this, modal popup works, screens show normal, dropup doesn't, dropdown menu doesn't*@
@*    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>*@


  @*  With this, dropdown menu works.  Modal popup doesn't.  Drop-up doesn't.*@
    
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/popper.js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
I have tried numerous combinations of bootstrap and popper script tags, and tried installing and deinstalling bootstrap and popper using Nuget.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpPw4.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted an answer and somehow, I deleted it by mistake when trying to add a screenshot for clarity.  Here is the _Layout header that works...

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="your-javascript-file.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```